# Custom checkBox in ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, checkbox, android-listview

In my application I have a `ListView` with custom rows and I want to add a custom `CheckBox` for each item, like this:

[image]

When I click on 'EDIT' I want the `ListView` translates to right and it appears a custom `CheckBox` at left from each `ListView`'s row.

Is it possible to maintain the `ListView` at right even if some row icons don't seen (like the star or arrow)? Or if I translate the `ListView` at right the row is compressed and all icons are visible?

I have put a `TranslateAnimation`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="17%"
    android:duration="750" />

</set>
```

and I have managed to translate the `ListView` but after 2 seconds it returns to the initial position ... how can I manage that the `ListView` maintains at right after `TranslateAnimation`?

Is it better to put a checkbox like 'gone' at left to the row and when 'EDIT' button is pushed to put all checkbox like visible? In this case, Does each row translate to right like the image or it would be compressed and all icons would be visible?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

My row xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@color/backgr_greysoft" >

   <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/row_information"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="@dimen/rowDescargas_height"
      android:background="@drawable/button_file"
      android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
      android:layout_margin="@dimen/rowDescargas_marginLateral"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:weightSum="1" >

      <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/icon"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="@dimen/rowDescargas_marginIcono"
         android:layout_weight="0.25" />

      <LinearLayout
      ...
      </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for, but [this](https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView) should give you a fair idea

Answer (score 1):

Yes, put a checkbox like `gone`. And set to your information view following:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Parent of this view should be `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="horizontal"`.

Comment: But, what width and weight I should put for CheckBox? Because if I put weight=1 for the other view ...

Comment: For `CheckBox` set `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`.

Answer (score 0):

custom_checkbox.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" 
          android:drawable="@xml/checked" /> 
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@xml/checked" /> 
    <item android:drawable="@xml/unchecked" /> 
</selector>
```

---

checked.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#ff2665B4" android:endColor="#ff2665B4" android:angle="270"/>
    <stroke android:width="4px" android:color="#ffc0c0c0" />
    <size android:height="20dp" android:width="20dp"/>
</shape>
```

---

unchecked.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#ffffff" android:endColor="#ffffff" android:angle="270"/>
    <stroke android:width="4px" android:color="#ffc0c0c0" />
    <size android:height="20dp" android:width="20dp"/>
</shape>
```

set in to checkBox

```
facilityCheck.setButtonDrawable(R.xml.custom_checkbox);


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@color/backgr_greysoft" >

<CheckBox 
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/chk_facility"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           />

      <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/icon"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_margin="@dimen/rowDescargas_marginIcono"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chk_facility" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I obtain a 'NullPointerException' with the last line ... (3 files are put in 'res/xml' folder)

Comment: facilityCheck is your checkbox which is in listview row xml file.

Comment: I already know it, I had problems with my Adapter class. Do you know what weight I should put to checkBox? Or not to put weight?

Comment: I think no need to put weight.

Comment: Please give me your row xml file.